# Bagging sample probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bootstrap, bagging

I know that the probability that an observation does not appear in the sample is $\left(1 - \frac{\ 1}{n} \right)^n ≈ \left(\frac{1}{e}\right) $ (when n is large). 
My question is how to find the probability that an observation appears exactly once and the probability that it appears exactly twice, and find similar approximations to them, using the same formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Poisson approximation to the binomial, where $p=1/n$, and $\lambda=np=1$.

Probability of appearing exactly $k$ times is $$p_X(k)={n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-k}\approx e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=\frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$$